# Generating a new variable/column in a data frame based on two rows of another variable/column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Context: I am working with Uniform Crime Report data, indexed by city(place). I am trying to merge/concat the years 2006-2016

Problem: Not all .csv's have a state column in front of the city name, and there are different numbers of cities in each file. Since there are duplicates in the city name column, merging without the second key is not possible (for me).

My solution: I made a new variable = the first letter of each city name, and a dictionary "A":1, "B":2,..."Z":26. Then I made another column with the value associated with each first letter. The goal is to subtract row n from row (n+1) and evaluate result => 0, or evaluate the inequality row(n+1)=>row(n)

I spent most of the day trying to do it in a list, such as:

```
    state = []
    statenum = 1
    for n in firstletter:
        if n+1 => n:
            state.append(statenum)
        else:
            statenum = statenum + 1
            state.append(statenum)
```

But I could not, for the life of me, figure out how to call the n+1 object in the list, rather than simply adding 1 to value of n.

It just occurred to me to try and do it in a dataframe, but I could not get that to work either.  I would be happy with a solution for either; it does not really need to be particularly efficient.

Comment: Do you mind to share your dataframe and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

> But I could not, for the life of me, figure out how to call the n+1 object in the list, rather than simply adding 1 to value of n.

If you want the next iteration object, you can do as such :

```
for index, n in enumerate(firstletter):
    n # it is your current object
    firstletter[index + 1] # it is your next object
```

Be careful though, as you don't want to search for the next iteration when you hit the last object, as you will raise an **IndexError**.

Comment: `enumerate(firstletter[:-1])` and you don't have to worry about going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, IMCoins & COLDSPEED.  I got it to work with this:

```
    testn = []
    state = 1
    for index, n in enumerate(ln[:-1]):
    c1 = n
    c2 = ln[index + 1] 
    if c2 >= c1:
        testn.append(state)
    else:
        state = state + 1
        testn.append(state)
```

I am certain it is the least efficient way possible to do it, but it works for me =)